# Import parts of a .xml to sql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, xml, import, keyword

I'm trying to import several parts of a .xml file into a mysql database using php. The parts I want to import are marked with a specific keyword. Is it possible to specify the import or research for certain keywords before importing ?

This is just a small extract of the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<kl_plan>
//this is the part I want to import:
   <pl>
      <pl_tag>day1</pl_tag>
      <pl_stunde>lesson1</pl_stunde>
      <pl_un>8</pl_un>
      <pl_fach>subject1</pl_fach>
      <pl_fachori>subject1</pl_fachori>
      <pl_klasse>class1</pl_klasse>
      <pl_lehrer legeaendert="legeaendert">Hr</pl_lehrer>  //"geaendert" is the keyword
      <pl_lehrerori>teacher1</pl_lehrerori>
      <pl_raum>room1</pl_raum>
   </pl>

//this is the information (with the normal format) I don't want to import:
   <pl>
      <pl_tag>day</pl_tag>
      <pl_stunde>lesson</pl_stunde>
      <pl_un>36</pl_un>
      <pl_fach>subject</pl_fach>
      <pl_fachori>subject</pl_fachori>
      <pl_klasse>class</pl_klasse>
      <pl_lehrer>teacher</pl_lehrer>
      <pl_lehrerori>teacher</pl_lehrerori>
      <pl_raum>room</pl_raum>
    </pl>
 </kl_plan>
```

There are different variations of the keyword (like: legeaendert, rageaendert, fageaendert)

I already have a code which imports the whole .xml file. This doesn't really help me because there is too much unnecessary information in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

hi for this you can use 
simplexml_load_string — Interprets a string of XML into an object

little example of use

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version='1.0'?> 
<document>
 <title>Forty What?</title>
 <from>Joe</from>
 <to>Jane</to>
 <body>
  I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
 </body>
</document>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);

print_r($xml);
```

example will output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
  [title] => Forty What?
  [from] => Joe
  [to] => Jane
  [body] =>
   I know that's the answer -- but what's the question?
)
```

try and good luck ...!!!